# How to do a Combined bake without the Diffuse contribution?

Tags: texture-baking

My goal is to bake a texture that has everything included except the diffuse of the material.
This is what I tried:
Combined bake with 'Diffuse' deselected.
This however left out more than only the Diffuse.
It left the Environment almost completely out.
Also the emission of other objects felt less strong.

My temporary (slow) solution is doing the Combined bake with Diffuse. And then the Diffuse bake. After both are done I manually substract the Diffuse from the Combined (with my own program)...

Edit:

This is Combined Bake:
[image]

This is Combined Bake with 'Diffuse' deselected:
[image]

My cube is blue, my environment is red and an adjacent object is green.
So apparently this test setup does give environment color in the bake..

---

@ sybog64
The green part is due to indirect lighting. This effect get omitted when using a black diffuse color (assuming the green object is part of the baked object). That is what I meant with scatter.

---

Back to my problem:

I think I misunderstood the concept of leaving the diffuse out..

So my (new) actual question is:
How do I combine the Diffuse and the Combined (without diffuse) to get the Combined:

Diffuse:
[image]

Combined Bake with 'Diffuse' deselected:
[image]

Combined:
[image]

Comment: If you want the diffuse component of your texture to be 0, set the diffuse component of your shader to pure black

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the scatter is removed in this way. And another reason why not to use this method is the unclear relationship to the end-result (mulitply / addition?)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by scatter. That sounds to me like diffusion, which is what a diffuse pass is. Are you trying to remove the diffuse pass from the shader or remove diffuse bounces from the light information ? Could you provide a file and illustrations of what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: why your edit is commendable, I still fail to understand what you're technically trying to achieve. perhaps the use case you have could help clear it up. What are you going to use this texture for that you need to exclude the diffuse ?

Comment: Im baking lightmaps for an old game (bf1942), This game multiplies the diffuse with the lightmap and divides it by 2. So I was wondering if this type of lightmap could be extracted directly with Blender. Thats why I asked `How do I combine the Diffuse and the Combined (without diffuse) to get the Combined?`
But I think it is not possible. So I use my own program to divide the diffuse out of the combined..
Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: so what you want is to extract the basecolor ? thing is the basecolor is whatever texture you're using. Unless that's procedural textures there's no baking to do

Comment: No, I want everything except the base color. So, I want the combined devided by the diffuse. Anyhow, how do I close a question?

Comment: ah, okay. You want to bake the lightmap, and apply that onto the albedo. Lightmap is literally the 'diffuse' data. So you'll do a diffuse bake and uncheck color from the contributions. Answer with pictures coming

Comment: The combined *should* be the combined-sans-diffuse pass plus the diffuse pass.  However, this addition should occur in linear color space, and your images may be in sRGB space.  Skipping a diffuse generally leaves out almost everything, because what's left is basically specular, where not all lighting gets baked because of the view-dependent nature of the specular pass.

Comment: @sybog64 Re: definitions.  It is very common to refer to the texture color sent to a diffuse pass as the diffuse color (this is *not* albedo, because there is also a specular pass and sometimes other passes, colors for which also contribute to albedo) and if you treat "diffuse" as referring only to the pass and not to the texture color, I think you're going to confuse people rather than educate them-- particularly if they're working in certain contexts like game dev.

Comment: @Nathan Some people do refer to the albedo as diffuse sometimes, it's still incorrect to do so.   In a context where 'Diffuse' already has 2-3 distinct meanings, it becomes crucial to name things carefuly.   'Diffuse' and 'Diffuse color' are too similar (tho the word color does change the meaning)
A pass contributing to albedo tho is just incorrect. perhaps you meant albedo contributes to them ? in any case 'base texture' is the NPR name for the texture you use to tint the diffuse pass. Furthermore, albedo does not contribute to the specular pass on dielectric materials.

Comment: @sybog64 https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/350/albedo-vs-diffuse represents my usage of the term.  Carmack's tweet at https://twitter.com/ID_AA_Carmack/status/56376080453480449 suggests similar expert usage (diffuse color is close to albedo, not the same thing as albedo.)  The "real" meaning of a word is an inarguable celestial teapot; all a word means is its usage.  If you tell a new user that diffuse refers only to a pass, a lot of things they read won't make sense until they unlearn that definition.  Here, hopefully, the comments will protect them from that.

Comment: @Nathan I'd like a direct way to chat with you about this, because it's legitimately interesting. In both of the examples you gave, diffuse to refer to the texture is used as an adjective, not the main noun. The distinction between "the Diffuse" and "the diffuse map/color/coefficient" is important. Because of the way blender names things specifically for this question, but also in a more general sense, it's more useful to understand diffuse does not directly refer to image/color data but a BSDF. words' meaning in a vacuum is not important, but when baking diffuse refers to something specific

Comment: @syborg64 I know, this isn't the right place for the discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's clear some terms up:

**Albedo** : the physical color of a surface. It doesn't depend on light. Usually textures before they are baked or shaded. synonym for base color

**Diffuse** : Type of light bounce. It is part of the shading, not of the texture data.

This is the setup I'm working with:

render: 
[image: render]

---

Blender's Combined baker will capture the exact tint of each texel if the camera angle was faced straight at it, including any gloss.

Blender's diffuse baker will capture the tint of each texel based only on the diffuse component of the object's material (it will use glossy bounces on other objects). This is basically for tinted lighting and shadows.

full diffuse:
[image: diffuse]

on a rough material, with not much specular detail, the diffuse and combined bake look pretty much identical.

---

Unchecking Color contribution from the diffuse baker will capture the shading as if the albedo was pure white.

lightmap:
[image: only shading info]

---

This can then be multiplied with any albedo to cheaply change the color of the object :

tinted lightmap:
[image: diffuse * albedo]

---

However, on non metallic materials, the glossy component is not multiplied with the albedo but added on top:

Tinted diffuse + glossy component :
[image: diffuse * albedo + glossy]

---

In conclusion, to get the lightmap, you want to bake the diffuse and uncheck color contribution:

[image: bake settings]

Comment: Great answer. I think this is the closest what I can come with a purely Blender based approach! Still, due to a weird game-engine I will have to post process my lightmaps